# Multiple security-realms for remoting in JBoss AS 7

Tags: jboss

I have two applications (ears) deployed on a JBoss 7.1.3 server. I want to access beans from both of these applications from a remote client using JNDI. However, I need password authentication for one of my applications, and want to access the other without any authentication.

For the first of my applications I defined a custom security realm and set it as the remoting-connectors security realm. The corresponding code snippets of the standalone.xml look like this:

Security Realm:

```
<security-realm name="CustomRealm">
    <authentication>
        <jaas name="CustomDomain"/>
    </authentication>
</security-realm>
```

Remoting Subsystem:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.1">
  <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="CustomRealm"/>
</subsystem>
```

What I would like to do is specify a second security realm (or better none at all) for my second application. I found pretty much the same question on the [JBoss Forum](https://community.jboss.org/thread/196943) but without an answer that solved my problem.

Is this possible and if so, how can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible currently due to the limitation of EJB Remoting subsytem in AS7. There is a issue opened on this already.. 
    https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-6367

Did you tried to expose this EJB as webservie? this way you can use different realm.